# How can I make a dialog box center in the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I resized my jQuery UI dialog box like this:

```
height: $(window).height(),
width: $(window).width(),
```

But now It's no longer in the center of the window. Is there some way I can make it become centered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below function- change the variable as per requirement

```
function positionLightboxImage() {
  var top = ($(window).height() - $('#lightbox').height()) / 2;
  var left = ($(window).width() - $('#lightbox').width()) / 2;
  console.log("The calculated position is:");
  console.log(top,left);
  $('#lightbox')
    .css({
      'top': top + $(document).scrollTop(),
      'left': left
    })
    .fadeIn();
  console.log('A jQuery selection:');
  console.log($('#lightbox'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifies where the dialog should be displayed. Possible values: 
1) a single string representing position within viewport: 'center', 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'. 
2) an array containing an x,y coordinate pair in pixel offset from left, top corner of viewport (e.g. [350,100]) 
3) an array containing x,y position string values (e.g. ['right','top'] for top right corner).

Code examples

Initialize a dialog with the position option specified.
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ position: 'top' });
Get or set the position option, after init.
//getter
var position = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", 'top' );

```
position : 'center'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dialog box uses `absolute` positioning, you can try this after resizing:

```
$('#dialog').animate({ 
    'top' : ($(window).height() - $('#dialog').outerHeight()) / 2 + $(document).scrollTop(),
    'left': ($(window).width() - $('#dialog').outerWidth()) / 2 + $(document).scrollLeft()
});
```

this will move the dialog box to the center.

Otherwise, in case the dialog box uses `fixed` positioning you can omit the `$(document).scrollTop()` and `$(document).scrollLeft()` from the calculation